# How to make a div to be responsive?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a problem with responsive of my div. I want that these two image when resize the window goes one below the other one. I have made a screenshot, so you can see exactly what I want. I'm not understand what's going wrong with my css code. Hope you help me.

```css
.gender-selector input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.women {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.man {
  position: relative;
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gender-selector">
  
  <label>
    <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="w" onclick="processPhase1()" />
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/female1-512.png" width="180px" height="180px" class="women">
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="m" onclick="processPhase1()" />
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png" width="180px" height="180px" class="man">
  </label>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is how do you try to position the images. I have to admit that I have no seen a label containing elements but text, not sure if that is w3 compliant. But this fiddle does what you need.

```
.women {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px; // this may be the issue
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4d9ueeL/

Just reduce the right panel (where the html is displayed) and you will be able to see the effect.

Regards

Comment: ... from there you can play with alignments and margins to center the content. I could help you as well if you need help on that.

Comment: i have tried that but i want a certain distance between the 2 images, how i can this

Comment: Here... https://jsfiddle.net/p4d9ueeL/1/... check the comment I placed on the css.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is something like this.  Wrap your `<labels>` in `<div>`'s your css would look something like this:

```
.gender-selector div {
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.gender-selector div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I am pretty sure that should give you close to what you are looking for, you might have to tweak the max width to make it perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. The following example we display the `labels` (blue border) beside each other using `display:inline-block`. They will then wrap one under the other when their container `.gender-selector` (red border) is too narrow for them to fit beside each other.

In this demo I've limited the width of `.gender-selector` to show the effect. Expand the snippet full-size to see them fit side-by-side.

```css
.gender-selector input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gender-selector {
  border:1px solid red;
  max-width:60%; 
  min-width:220px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.gender-selector label {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
.gender-selector label img {
  padding:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gender-selector">
  <label>
    <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="w" onclick="processPhase1()" />
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/female1-512.png" width="180px" height="180px" class="women">
  </label><!-- no whitespace here
--><label>
    <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="m" onclick="processPhase1()" />
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png" width="180px" height="180px" class="man">
  </label>

</div>
```